# Saving Javascript object that has an array of Parse.files causes "Converting circular structure to JSON" error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm running into a problem where parse.com doesn't like it when I try to upload an array of parse files to parse.

I currently have an array (arr) that is filled with base64 string image data

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var pfile = new Parse.File("photo", { base64: arr[i] });
    pfile.save();
    parseArr.push(pfile);
}
```

When I attempt to save the array to a column called "images" to parse.com data browser, I run into an error:

```
posts.set("images", parseArr)
```

I end up with this error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at _.extend._resetCacheForKey (../node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4957:25)
```

Is there anyway I can upload multiple photos that will show up in one column in parse.com?
Here's an archived section of parse.com's question but they require a change in the source code to circumvent the problem.

[Reference to the parse.com archive question forum](https://www.parse.com/questions/saving-javascript-object-that-has-an-array-of-parsefiles-causes-converting-circular-structure-to-json-error)

Help?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. One workaround I can think of is to instead have an array column of `pfile._url` which is the url of the newly created parse.file object. Though I'm not sure if the file will eventually get garbage collected :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Final Update**: Good news! A fix has been made and will be released in the next Javascript SDK release 1.6.0.

[image: BugMe]

Answer (score 1):

Before saving the array, I converted each Parse.File into a custom object containing the same attributes as the file, including `__type`.

```
var convertedFiles = [];
_.each(files, function (file) {
    var data = { __type = 'File', name: file.name, url: file.url() };
    convertedFiles.push(data);
});
parseObj.set('files', convertedFiles);
parseObj.save();
```

While a client fetches these converted objects, they interpret each of them as a Parse.File.