# associating an array of photos with a user on parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload several user photos to parse.com and associate them with a user object. I'm using the javascript sdk https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-types
I'm able to successfully save the photo as a file object. But when I try to build an array column in the user object/table the sdk errors out.

I get the error `JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.` upon saving the user object.

**profileController.js**

```
// uploads photo to rest api given local file_uri
$scope.addPhoto = function() {

  var file = new Parse.File("profile-image.jpeg", { base64: $scope.imageData });
  file.save().then(function(res) {
    console.log('success', res);
    var array = ['foo', file];
    $scope.user.set('photos', array);
    $scope.user.save();
  }, function(error) {
      console.log('error', error);
  });
};
```

This error arises when the object being serialized holds references to itself. My question then is - Is there a way to associate all user image files with a user object on parse.com? Ideally as an array column because I know there will never be more than 5 profile images per user.[image: file object]

Comment: it's an open bug in the sdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297590/saving-javascript-object-that-has-an-array-of-parse-files-causes-converting-cir

Comment: avoid the 'cyclic' bug by using another class to hold the array that has the files.  in _User  add a column that is a pointer to the new Class object containing the photo array. its not that hard to do a flat query that gets both the _User and the Class.pic.arrayHolder any time you just wanted the _User.

Comment: @RobertRowntree for now I'm just storing an array column on user made up of the urls for the files. This will probably break if I ever initiate a garbage collection correct? Also could you write up your proposal as an answer? A diagram would be great

Comment: Its parse. go with whatever works. dont worry about GC

Comment: @RobertRowntree let me qualify that. Parse says if you initiate a GC all unreference files will get removed. My question is if I just keep the urlstring in some table is that a reference? I think not. I think GC abating refs are like pointer columns and such.

Comment: URL hanging around in some field may not prevent GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PictureHolder.Class

```
 {"photos":["url": $parseFile1, "url":$parseFile2, "url":$parseFile3...]}
```

_User contains the following pointer column.

{"linkPhotos":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"PictureHolder","objectId":$ID_Pointed_TO}}

flat query on _User table just add following to the Query.parms...

```
 include=linkPhotos
```

that will inline into the Json response, the full, linked row from the 2nd table.